Unable to render mat-list-option in ng-content: No provider for InjectionToken SelectionList
The archivement is to use a base component where I would be able to render a default list of items or a customized one, to do so I've create a base component that has the mat-select-list in it like this:
<mat-selection-list class="pt-0" [multiple]="false" #list>
    <ng-content>
    @for (item of items(); track $index) {
        <mat-list-option [value]="{ id: item.id, name: item.name }">{{ item.name }}</mat-list-option>
    }            
    </ng-content>
</mat-selection-list>

The base mat-list-option has as the value the { id: item.id, name: item.name } and as the content {{ item.name }}, when I use this base component without passing any ng-content so by using the default one, I have no issues and the component behave as it has to.
The issue is when I try to use a custom in ng-content in a component like this:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-select-modal',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BaseSelectModalComponent, MatListOption],
  template: `
    <app-base-select-modal title="Seleziona la licenza" [items]="items()" [itemsCount]="count()" [isLoading]="isLoading()" (onClose)="close()" (onConfirm)="confirm($event)">
      @for (item of items(); track $index) {
          <mat-list-option [value]="item">
            <div>{{ item.product.name }}</div>
            <span>{{ item.key }}</span>
          </mat-list-option>
      }
    </app-base-select-modal>
  `,
})
export class LicenseSelectModalComponent {
...
}

I just get NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken SelectionList! error when the base-select-modal is trying to render.
I've tried yet to import MatListModule even in the LicenseSelectModalComponent but it has no effect.
Here is the base-select-modal:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-select-modal',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatDialogModule, MatButton, MatFormField, MatInput, MatLabel, MatListModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule],
  templateUrl: './base-select-modal.component.html',
  styleUrl: './base-select-modal.component.scss',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class BaseSelectModalComponent {
...
}


The mat-list-option requires mat-selection-list to be the parent. That is why you are getting this error. To solve the error, you must pass the selection list as the ng-content, or provide a custom template that the for loop renders inside the app-base-select-modal component.
Here is a stackblitz showing the use of ng-template and signals to pass the template and conditionally render it.
list-selection-example.ts
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { InnerComponent } from 'src/app/inner/inner.component';

/**
 * @title List with selection
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'list-selection-example',
  templateUrl: 'list-selection-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatListModule, InnerComponent],
})
export class ListSelectionExample {
  typesOfShoes: string[] = [
    'Boots',
    'Clogs',
    'Loafers',
    'Moccasins',
    'Sneakers',
  ];
  items = signal([
    { key: 1, id: 1, product: { name: 'test1' }, name: 'test1' },
    { key: 2, id: 2, product: { name: 'test2' }, name: 'test2' },
    { key: 3, id: 3, product: { name: 'test3' }, name: 'test3' },
    { key: 4, id: 4, product: { name: 'test4' }, name: 'test4' },
    { key: 5, id: 5, product: { name: 'test5' }, name: 'test5' },
  ]);
}

list-selection-example.html
<app-base-select-modal
  title="Seleziona la licenza"
  [items]="items()"
  [optionTemplate]="optionTemplate"
>
</app-base-select-modal>
<hr />
<app-base-select-modal title="Seleziona la licenza" [items]="items()">
</app-base-select-modal>
<ng-template let-item="item" #optionTemplate>
  <div>{{ item.product.name }}</div>
  <span>{{ item.key }}</span>
</ng-template>

inner.component.ts
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  input,
  InputSignal,
  TemplateRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatButton } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFormField } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-select-modal',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButton,
    MatFormField,
    MatInput,
    MatListModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  template: `
  <mat-selection-list class="pt-0" [multiple]="false" #list>
      @for (item of items(); track $index) {
        @if(optionTemplate(); as optionTemplateRef) {
          <mat-list-option [value]="item">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="optionTemplateRef;context:{item: item}"></ng-container>
          </mat-list-option>
        } @else{
          <mat-list-option [value]="{ id: item.id, name: item.name }">{{ item.name }}</mat-list-option>
        }
        
      }            
  </mat-selection-list>
  `,
  styleUrl: './inner.component.scss',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class InnerComponent {
  items: InputSignal<any> = input([]);
  optionTemplate: InputSignal<TemplateRef<any> | undefined> = input();
}

Stackblitz Demo

I was testing almost the same solution, but the main issue was that the list was rendering but the template in ng-content was not, by checking your code I've notice that I was missing the CommonModule import!

I've just found a solution to the: No provider for InjectionToken SelectionList but it resolve the functional issue only in part.
Instead of passing only the @for to ng-content I've wrap the whole mat-selection-list in it so in the component I now use it like this:
<app-base-select-modal title="Seleziona la licenza" [items]="items()" [itemsCount]="count()" [isLoading]="isLoading()" (onClose)="close()" (onConfirm)="confirm($event)">
  
<mat-selection-list class="pt-0" [multiple]="false" #list>
  @for (item of items(); track $index) {
      <mat-list-option [value]="item">
        <div>{{ item.product.name }}</div>
        <span>{{ item.key }}</span>
      </mat-list-option>
  }
  </mat-selection-list>
</app-base-select-modal>

The issue here is that when an item from the selection list is selected, it is not propagated to base-select-modal.
So I'm still looking for an elegant way to make the base-select-modal reusable and customizable.
